# Internet Explorer Displaying Binary Image Data

Tags: php, internet-explorer, blob, mime-types

The following code snippet works in all browsers except Internet Explorer. Every browser (Chrome, FF, Safari, & Opera) displays the following as an image, however Internet Explorer displays the binary data (letters and symbols).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// code compiling $myimageblob

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $myimageblob;
```

Comment: make sure, you don't send any output before header and after image source.

Comment: My original code used double quotations; but after switching to the single quotes as displayed in my original post, the binary data is now displaying and not the image itself.

Comment: Decided to use a data URI scheme instead.